# How to get surrounding tiles in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a peace of code, in which I need to find all surrounding tiles of a tile. I can get the target tile, but cannot find the way to get it's neighbors.

Here is the code I have:

```
public List<TileBase> FindAllTileNeighbors(Vector2 gameOjectPosition){
    List<TileBase> sTiles;
    GridLayout grid = map.GetComponentInParent<GridLayout>();
    Vector3Int gridPosition = grid.WorldToCell(gameOjectPosition);
    TileBase tile = map.GetTile(gridPosition);

    // TODO: find surrounding tiles

    return sTiles;
}
```

Comment: If you have an array then maybe the easiest way is to find neighbours using
1) [x - 1, y]
2) [x + 1, y]
3) [x, y - 1]
4) [x, y + 1]

Comment: Hi @NishchhalBakshi, thanks for your reply. I am very new to Unity, hence don't yet know how to implement that. Would you be so kind to give an asnwer with a code example?

Comment: How do you store your tiles? I can see a List of TileBase, do you spawn them?
If you do spawn them then maybe use an array if you want to find neighbours.
For array you can read about what are arrays and how you can add items based on index and retrieve items from it.

Comment: @NishchhalBakshi I made scriptable objects of tiles to store some data in them. Then I put a get object on it, and based on position of the game object I get current tile. You can see it in the code. But then, I need to find what are the surrounding tiles. And yes, I know how to add items into array, I just don't know how to find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"All neighbours" is a bit unspecific.

From you only passing in a 2D position I'd assume you only want to find neighbours within the XY plane.

You already have the `gridPosition` so you could simply do

```
// This allows you to use queries on IEnumerable types
// see example at the bottom
using System.Linq;

...

private readonly Vector3Int[] neighbourPositions = 
{
    Vector3Int.up,
    Vector3Int.right,
    Vector3Int.down,
    Vector3Int.left,
    
    // if you also wanted to get diagonal neighbours
    //Vector3Int.up + Vector3Int.right,
    //Vector3Int.up + Vector3Int.left,
    //Vector3Int.down + Vector3Int.right,
    //Vector3Int.down + Vector3Int.left
};

public List<TileBase> FindAllTileNeighbors(Vector2 gameOjectPosition)
{  
    var grid = map.GetComponentInParent<GridLayout>();
    var gridPosition = grid.WorldToCell(gameOjectPosition);
    
    if(!map.HasTile(gridPosition))
    {
        Debug.LogWarning($"The position {gridPosition} does not exist in the map!");
        return new List<TileBase>();
    }

    var sTiles = new List<TileBase>();
    foreach(var neighbourPosition in neighbourPositions)
    {
        var position = gridPosition + neighbourPosition;

        if(map.HasTile(position))
        {
            var neighbour = map.GetTile(position);
            sTiles.Add(neighbour);
        }
    }
    return sTiles;

    // or using Linq you could also write it as
    //return (from neighbourPosition in neighbourPositions select gridPosition + neighbourPosition into position where map.HasTile(position) select map.GetTile(position)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to specify that I need neighbours within the XY. Very nice of you adding comments, it's clearly explains what does what :) Many thanks for you help!